# NPM install --global command Proxy Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, http-proxy

Hi I have installed Node JS version 10  and Npm version 6, in my system.
When I 'm trying to hit command

```
npm install -g yarn
```

It gives me error
[image]

Then i have added proxy by searching commands

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyname.com:portno
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxyname.com:portno
```

even i have added domain as well prefix of username like

```
doamin%5C
```

then error gets change please look down below
[image]

Also i have already addded

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

**Also already added strict ssl false as well**

Please provide me the solution,any how thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.npmrc` file, usually found on the path `~/.npmrc` on Mac/Linux.

See if the values, especially the proxy, has been set properly, like

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxyname.com:portno
```

Check if the value for `proxy` is complete with proper URL encoding.

Note:

1. If your username/password contains any special characters you need to URL encode them. Eg. If your username is `bruce\wayne` then you need to URL encode it as `bruce%5Cwayne` where %5C="\"
2. If your proxy has no authentication then ignore  and

Examples:

```
npm config set proxy http://bruce%5Cwayne:darkknight@11.434.2.23:8080
```

Also, you don't need to do this,

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Because by default npm will try to access  `http://registry.npmjs.org/`
This is useful only if you want npm to access your private registry(like when hosted using Artifactory)

Comment: I have # in password so how can i encode please let me know

Comment: @Madhur # URL encoded is %23
Use an online tool to do URL encoding and decoding, like this https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: lets suppose my command is
nmp config set proxy http://username:pasword%23@doamin.8080
Please correct if am not wrong

Comment: Looking from your comment it would be something like ```npm config set proxy http://username:pasword%23@host:8080``` here ```%23``` would be ```#```.
**Example**:  If your ```username=brucewayne``` and ```password=darkknight#``` then you should execute ```npm config set proxy http://brucewayne:darkknight%23@11.434.2.23:8080```

Comment: You are the,live saver man, I just need to encode this thing only it worked

Comment: Great! Have fun coding! :)

Comment: do you have an idea , If npm install -g (command)
if any command not found what will need to do for that.
it gives me error 404 not found